# C# - why Histogram does not work in Excel 2016?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-charts

I have excel 2016 vsto application build in c#. I have a chart control and want to set chart type to the histogram. I can select this chart from excel but I am not able set this chart type programmatically. 
[image]

In other words, I am not able to find histogram chart type in the XlChartType enum.

Comment: Have you tried inserting one through the interface and then checking its `Type` via code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases you should always open Object Browser in excel macros and and search for what you are looking for

[image: histogram]

As you can see from object browser, the value for histogram is `118` or `76` in hex. You can use the same in your code directly by defining a constant

**Edit-1: The code**

Debugging your code below I found a issue

```
Worksheet sheet1 = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.Sheet1.Application.Worksheets[1]);
//chartTest
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)sheet1.ChartObjects("chartTest");
myChart.Chart.SetSourceData(sheet1.Range["A1", "A51"]);
myChart.Chart.Type = 118;
```

What you need to do is assign `118` to `ChartType` and not `Type`. Below code worked fine for me

```
Worksheet sheet1 = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.Sheet1.Application.Worksheets[1]);
//chartTest
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)sheet1.ChartObjects("chartTest");
myChart.Chart.SetSourceData(sheet1.Range["A1", "A51"]);
Excel.XlChartType myType = (Excel.XlChartType)118;

myChart.Chart.ChartType = myType;
```

Comment: I tried to set myChart.Chart.Type = 118 and I am getting "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component".

Comment: @user781700, possible to get a minimal repo to debug?

Comment: @user781700, please provide a link which doesn't require a signup and a paid account

Comment: Here is the free download link: http://www.filedropper.com/https://ufile.io/es8bc

Comment: @user781700, please check the edit. The code now works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Simply record a Macro while you add a Histogram to your sheet.

Stop recording and press Alt+F11 to open the Visual Basic Editor. Open the recoded macro and convert/compare the VBA to C# code.