# c# interop excel creating histogram

Tags: c#, excel, histogram, excel-interop

I want to create a histogram on a already existent spreadsheet `xlWorkSheetDia` which displays data in the spreadsheet `xlWorkSheetData`.

The main problem I have is creating the histogram chart because `Excel.XlChartType`does not suggest me the `xlHistogram`Enumerator. I tried looking up the enumerator and creating it by myself following the suggestions in this question: [C# - why Histogram does not work in Excel 2016?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959831/c-sharp-why-histogram-does-not-work-in-excel-2016)

I looked up the enumerator number with the object explorer, it also is 118 (decimal). But I get an out of range exception when applying the chart type.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            try
            {
                string path = @"C:\TestData.csv";
                string destPath = @"C:\TestData.txt";
                //Create an instance for word app
                Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetDia, xlWorkSheetData;
                xlApp.Visible = true;  //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.

                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName: path, destFileName: destPath, overwrite: true); // use txt file instead of csv, for correct delimiter parsing
                //Open WorkBook to have csv Data
                xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText(destPath, DataType: Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, Semicolon: true);
                //Creating necessary objects
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
                xlWorkSheetData = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];
                xlWorkSheetData.Name = "Data";
                xlWorkSheetDia = xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
                xlWorkSheetDia.Name = "Diagrams";

                //Add chart 
                var charts = xlWorkSheetDia.ChartObjects() as Excel.ChartObjects;
                var chartObject = charts.Add(60, 10, 300, 300) as Excel.ChartObject;
                var chart = chartObject.Chart;
                //Move Chart
                chartObject.Chart.Location(Where: Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsObject, Name:xlWorkSheetDia.Name); //already gets created on the right place(first spreadsheet)
                //Set chart range
                chart.SetSourceData(xlWorkSheetData.get_Range("A1", "A5"));//Data on second spreadsheet
                //Set chart properties.
                Excel.XlChartType myHistogram = (Excel.XlChartType) 118;


                chart.ChartType = myHistogram; //<-The exception happens here


                //cleanup
                xlWorkBook.Close(false);
                xlApp.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And some test data:

```
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;O;P;Q;R;S;
2,138;2,066;2,022;2,076;0,297;0;0;0,77;1,898;1,864;1,798;1,859;1,715;20,032;8,599;0,039;0;0;0,336;Iteration: 5 of 500
0,298;0,295;0,298;0,297;0,297;0;0;0,302;0,296;0,296;0,297;0,297;0,299;0,3;0,296;0,037;0;0;0,409;Iteration: 6 of 500
0,297;0,299;0,296;0,297;0,311;0;0;0,295;0,295;0,295;0,295;0,295;0,295;0,306;0,306;0,039;0;0;0,372;Iteration: 7 of 500
0,299;0,298;0,295;0,297;0,295;0;0;0,294;0,307;0,295;0,295;0,296;0,297;0,296;0,295;0,04;0;0;0,368;Iteration: 8 of 500
```

When I tried to record a macro for creating a histogram, I get following commands:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    Range("A1:A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart 1")).Select
End Sub
```

Which is, in my opinion, totally different compared to the way I try it in my code example. I don't know how I should write this in C# because I don't have the same methods.

Any suggestions or hints how I can solve my problem?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you forgot to tell us that your program fails like that only when you run it on another machine.  Its Office version needs to be updated.

Comment: You mean it only fails on my machine because I use Office2016?